# Cross domain AJAX in android

Tags: android, ajax, browser, proxy, webserver

I have a local HTML file (e.g. `file:///xxx.html`) containing AJAX code to read and process contents of pages on remote hosts (that are not my own). On desktop, I do this by running a local web server that returns remote data (I use `Nginx` with `proxy_pass` on specific url patterns). For example, if I want to get data from `http://example.com/`, I use `JQuery`'s `ajax` with `http://localhost:9000/http://example.com/` as the URL.

How can I do this on (non-rooted) Android? Is there an Android web server that supports `proxy_pass` on specific url patterns? Or is there an Android app/browser that allows cross-domain AJAX requests from local HTML files? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

By default from Any Android Browser starting from Android 2.1, it supports CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) feature. Check: http://caniuse.com/cors

In addition, The REST service also need to configure to allow cors from **Server Side** as well. For enabling at Server side set an attribute in Response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

For more refer: http://enable-cors.org/server.html